# linking ViewModel to view using MvvmCross

Tags: android, view, xamarin, viewmodel, mvvmcross

I am using mvvmcross Framework in xamarin android application and My ViewModel is inheriting From mvxactivity and View is inhering from FragmentActivity . 
How to link ViewModel To View ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use generics to connect your viewmodel to a view.

```
public MyActivity : MvxActivity<MyViewModel>
{
     //Do some stuff in here. Like setting your content
}
```

A full example is available here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/tree/master/Samples

Comment: Link is broken.